# Incorrect column data in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I currently am using highchart for data display, however the data is not displaying correctly everytime the page is accessed.

The total number of RFI first shows 17 which is incorrect, and when I drilldown, the ongoing and closed RFIs shows 17 and 151 correctly.When I drill back up, the total RFI becomes 168 which is the correct one.

Can anyone explain why this might occur?

[Total RFI showing 17 instead of the total which is 168.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UGkQ.png)

I can't attach a 3rd picture, but when i drill down, it will show the correct numbers, which is ongoing 17 and closed 151.

[Total is now 168 after drillup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUzWD.png)

Comment: Can you debbug the var which contains that column data?, show code, plz ;)

Comment: the var tha contain the column data is an array of object literal. I printed it onto console and it shows 
name: In-DBS.....
y:168

Comment: can you share the code where you fill that array, and where you setdata to the chart?

Comment: Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to recreate a live example, e.g. on jsfiddle - or at least paste the code which will allow to reproduce your problem.